# On AMD Ryzen 2700X + RTX 2080 + Ubuntu 18.04 stack system freeze happens regularly

Tags: freeze, nvidia-geforce, ubuntu-18.04, amd-ryzen

I use the aforementioned setup for deep learning calculations using python MXNet.

When I was using unity/gnome, before crashes `journactl` reported something like this (always gnome-related process crashed first):

```
kov. 28 14:04:51 emil-NNNgine gnome-control-c[19370]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
kov. 28 14:04:51 emil-NNNgine gnome-control-c[19370]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
kov. 28 14:04:51 emil-NNNgine gnome-control-c[19370]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
kov. 28 14:04:51 emil-NNNgine gnome-control-c[19370]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
kov. 28 14:04:51 emil-NNNgine gnome-control-c[19370]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
kov. 28 14:17:01 emil-NNNgine CRON[22454]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
kov. 28 14:17:01 emil-NNNgine CRON[22455]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
kov. 28 14:17:01 emil-NNNgine CRON[22454]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine gnome-shell[1564]: Object .Gjs_AppIndicatorIconActor__1 (0x563d31d7d9d0), has been already finalized. Impossib
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: == Stack trace for context 0x563d2cba9330 ==
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #0 0x7ffd571eb540 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:83 (0x7f1288
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #1 0x563d2d043948 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ub
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #2 0x7ffd571ec8a0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f1288
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #3 0x7ffd571ec960 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f12886f12b8 @ 367)
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #4 0x7ffd571eca50 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f128
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #5 0x563d2d0438c0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ub
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #6 0x7ffd571eddb0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f1288
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #7 0x563d2d043818 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ub
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #8 0x7ffd571ef110 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f1288
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #9 0x563d2d0437a0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ub
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #10 0x563d2d0436e0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:82 (0x
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #11 0x563d2d043660 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:344 (0
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #12 0x7ffd571efe80 b   self-hosted:251 (0x7f12886c4ab0 @ 223)
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #13 0x563d2d0435e0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:343 (0
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #14 0x563d2d043560 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:361 (0
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #15 0x7ffd571f1380 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f12
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #16 0x7ffd571f1b90 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/sessionMode.js:205 (0x7f1
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #17 0x7ffd571f2870 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f128
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #18 0x563d2d043420 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/sessionMode.js:167 (0x7f1
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #19 0x7ffd571f3450 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f128
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #20 0x563d2d043378 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:1282 (0x7
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #21 0x7ffd571f4030 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f128
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #22 0x563d2d0432f0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:902 (0x7f
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #23 0x7ffd571f4c10 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f128
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #24 0x7ffd571f53b0 b   self-hosted:916 (0x7f12886f12b8 @ 367)
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #25 0x7ffd571f54a0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f12
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #26 0x563d2d043270 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/lightbox.js:186 (0x7f1288
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #27 0x7ffd571f6940 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:208
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #28 0x7ffd571f7190 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:337
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #29 0x7ffd571f7240 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:350
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #30 0x7ffd571f72d0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:365
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #31 0x7ffd571f7350 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f12
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #32 0x7ffd571f7400 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:244 (0x7f12886
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #33 0x7ffd571f7470 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f128
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1564]: #34 0x7ffd571f7470 I   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:219 (0x7f12886
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine gnome-software[1966]: no app for changed ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
kov. 28 14:20:03 emil-NNNgine gnome-software[1966]: no app for changed ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
-- Reboot --
kov. 28 14:26:03 emil-NNNgine kernel: Linux version 4.18.0-16-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-
```

`-- Reboot --` was when I noticed that system freezed and pressed reboot button.

Now, I've switched to xfce4 desktop manager. It run for a long hour, and I gave it overnight test. When I was back to PC, the screen was showing random rectangular colored patches. Last line in the `journalctl` says:

```
snapd[911]: stateengine.go:102: state ensure error: cannot refresh snap-declaration for "core": Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-declaration/16/*******?max-format=3: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: no such host
```

I am not sure if the problem is really ubuntu desktop manager not talking with NVidia correctly, or it is NVidia driver problems, or it is Ryzen problems...

Maybe anyone has some clues?

IMPORTANT UPDATE: in all cases when it was possible to trace, crash happened during np.loadtxt(...) operation of a very large file (training dataset, actually).

Comment: Are you using the same GPU for deep learning AND displaying the desktop?

Comment: Yes, I do. Didn't think it is actually possible to do otherwise. Is it?!

Comment: Please see update in the end of the question.

Comment: Currently investigating power supply common current idle option on Ryzen: https://community.amd.com/thread/225795 ...

Comment: Most likely you are using up the RAM on the GPU with deep learning, making desktop-related calls to GPU-functions fail. This results in screen artifacts (as seen) and X crashes (and thus desktop malfunctions). Best practice is to use different GPUs for ML and display or run the ML on a server without a GUI.

Comment: @EugenRieck , I monitor GPU usage with <code>nvidia-smi</code> constantly - it does not exceed 700MB for python process, and does not exceed 800MB total.

Comment: Just remark, setting Common Current Idle to "Typical" in BIOS didn't help.